# Standardize a dataset with dummy variables in python while solving a regression problem

Tags: python, regression, gis, geopandas

In a GIS problem, suppose I want to do a regression analysis on a dataset with 6 attributes from a to e as independent variables, for example:

a, b, c, d, e, f

5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0

e and f here are dummy variables, which can only be 0 or 1. Now I want to standardize this dataset for regression preparation, but I have to avoid standardizing e and f. A normal standardize code is like below:

```
##define a standardization function

def standardize_data(data, stats):
    return (data - stats['mean'])/ stats['std']

## Complete standardization

data_standardized = standardize_data(dataset, dataset_statistic)
```

Here is the problem, if I directly conduct this part, the dummy variable will be also taken into standardization, how should I avoid this with right format?

I try code like this:

```
data_standardized = standardize_data(dataset[a,b,c,d], dataset_statistic)
```

It returns error

> KeyError: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

Comment: Yes, just standardise the non-dummy columns. You could feed just those columns into the function

Comment: what is the correct format? Should I write like this: data_standardizd = standarize_data(dataset[a,b,c,d], dataset_statistic)?